# Is there Java counterpart for Aspnet 4's <%: %> XSS prevention?

Tags: java, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xss

I'm developer moving from C# to Java. Heard about new ASP net feature. 
<%: %>. It renders object with html encoding. Only these impolementing IHtmlString interface are not encoded (to prevent double encoding).
See more in http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Is such cute tool in Java side? I mean a way to output a string to webpage and (not)encode it based on it's type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is nothing in java that does this. You can create your own taglib to implement such a thing though.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure this is what you need, but we're using `c:out` in our JSPs for a similar purpose. See here: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html

Via `escapeXml` you can specify whether characters <,>,&,'," in the resulting string should be converted to their corresponding character entity codes. Default value is true.

Comment: It's not what I want. For me is Important where the decision to (not) HTML encode is done. In c:out it's in the page. Should be decided by the type of information rendered.